# How do I activate the Chunky Kong switch outside Gloomy Galleon's entrance?

Tags: donkey-kong-64

There is a switch with Chunky Kong's face outside the entrance to Gloomy Galleon. Unlike other switches, nothing happens when I ground pound it as Chunky. Why can't I activate this Chunky Kong switch?

[image: Chunky Kong switch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blue Kong Switches are activated with the Super [Simian Slam](https://www.mariowiki.com/Simian_Slam) move. You can purchase it from from Cranky Kong once you've reached Fungi Forest.